# rails how to translate keys on YAML files?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Let say I have this on my locale folder

```
es:
  books:
    index:
      title: "Título"
```

how do I put translation for `books`? or `index`?

Comment: You can use the new tool "attranslate" for YAML files: https://github.com/fkirc/attranslate This tool offers an optional mix and match of manual translations with machine translations.

Answer (score 0):

Change your es.yml to look like this:

```
es:
  activerecord:
    models:
      book:
        one: "Libro"
        other: "Libros"
    attributes:
      book:
        index: "índice"
...
```

See the rails i18n documentation section on [Translations for Active Record Models](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html#translations-for-active-record-models) for details.

Comment: I think I need to re-organize my locale files. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Simple translate in rails its

```
    # config/locales/Your_lang_here(en for now).yml
en:
  hello_world: Hello world!
  hello_flash: Hello flash!
  title: "Título"
```

so here `title` would be key to your translation

and you can use it on your view or where you want like `t('title')` and translation would be `Título`

[documentation here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html)